# Import Text File into SQL Server Database using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to import text file into sql server database and the import is working fine but the problem is that all the columns in the text file is being inserted into one column.
[image]

I need the columns from the text file to map the columns in the sql table.
here is my code

```
Console.WriteLine(s);
         string fileName = s.ToString();
         string fullPath = path + fileName.ToString();

         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Environment", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Job_Name", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Occurs",typeof(string)) });


         string csvData = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
         foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
         {
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
           {
             dt.Rows.Add();
             int i = 0;
             foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
             {
               dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
               i++;
             }
           }
         }

         string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString;
         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
         {
           using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
           {
             //Set the database table name
             sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[test2]";
             con.Open();
             sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
             con.Close();
           }
         }
```

Comment: So what exactly does row.Split(',') return?

Comment: Are the iterations actually happening in that first loop? I'm guessing the row terminator you are using isn't being parsed correctly, and so you it reads the entire file as 1 row then adds it.

Comment: I suggest you use `File.ReadAllLines` rather than splitting on `\n`. Also, are you sure your data is comma separated? Could it be a tab or spaces?

Comment: no my data is not comma separated, it is just regular text file (tab delimited text file)

Comment: If it's tab delimited then why are you using a comma? Do this: `row.Split('\t')` instead.

Comment: i thought it would work but i am also newbie trying to figure out solution that works..

Comment: Why would you think that splitting on a comma would work when you already know that your data is not marked out by commas? That just makes no logical sense, newbie or not. The same logic would apply if you were doing this with a piece of paper.

Comment: *CSV* = "Comma Separated Values". If your values are separated by the tab character then using a comma will never work right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are splitting your rows on comma when your data is tab separated. Instead do this:

```
row.Split('\t')
```

Also, don't split your entire file on `\n`, use `File.ReadAllLines`, for example:

```
 foreach (string row in File.ReadAllLines(fullPath))
 {
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
   {
     dt.Rows.Add();
     int i = 0;
     foreach (string cell in row.Split('\t'))
     {
       dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
       i++;
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below c# function import comma delimited file into C# dataTable. After getting data into dataTable you can apply your desired methods(Bulk Insert / Row by row) to take in DB :

```
 public static DataTable ImportDataFromCSVFile(string filePath)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string line;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                string[] row;
                int counter = 0;
                int length = 0;
                while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    row = line.Split(',');

                    if (counter == 0)
                    {
                        length = row.Length;
                        DataRow dr1 = dataTable.NewRow();
                        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                //dataTable.Columns.Add("Col_" + i.ToString());
                                dataTable.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(row[i]));

                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                        //  dataTable.Rows.Add(dr1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (row.Length == dataTable.Columns.Count)
                        {
                            DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
                            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                            {
                                if (row[i].ToString().Contains('"'))
                                {
                                    row[i] = row[i].Replace('"', ' ');
                                }
                                dr[i] = Convert.ToString(row[i]);
                            }

                            dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);

                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }

                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```